# Failed to start User Manager for UID 121 (BOOT)

Tags: permissions, root, system

[Here is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXcGn.jpg)

And when i type it, i have
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RthLK.jpg)

When i tried to start it from recovery terminal i got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LB0Uc.jpg)